# Comparing heavy tailed and non-heavy tailed distribution using Mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, visualization, histograms

I have data from a  heavy tailed  distribution (see picture 1) and a non-heavy tailed distribution (see picture 2) and want to compare it using a histogram on log-scale. However the picture 3 does not really help because it does not resolve the different scales. I would also like to plot the mean and standard deviation using error bars. The notebook I used to generate these plots is available under [notebook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2cnd3ec2006w013/stackexchangequestion.nb?dl=0)

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

[image: data 1]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Personally, I'd consider the first distribution to have a heavier tail than the second precisely because of the difference in horizontal scale.

Comment: Based on a recent SIAM Review paper that looked at real world data, it's difficult to draw a boundary between exponential and power (empirical, ie observed) distributions.

Comment: probably `Skewness` may help

Comment: @rcollyer sorry the reference to pictures was wrong way round

Comment: Histograms with the vertical axis on a log scale have never made much sense to me.  (But they do tend to show up in this forum not infrequently.)  And comparing moments (mean and standard deviations) for heavy tailed distributions (in part because for some heavy tailed distributions moments don't exist for the parent distribution even though on can calculate a moment for any particular sample) are rarely informative.

Comment: You might want to consider what characteristics of the (unknown) parent distributions would show the differences that you are envisioning.  Then one would figure out how to estimate that characteristic from a sample.  Maybe some of the heavy-tailed summary statistics might be what you're after:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution.  In essence start with the definition of the characteristic of interest as what it is to be compared is not an intrinsic feature of a parent distribution or of any sample.